# Nodejs/Azure - How to set url metadata in startCopyBlob

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am saving an image from a url to a blob using startCopyBlob.

I see from the documentation that I can set metadata too, however, I am struggling here when adding a url to the metadata

https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#startCopyBlob__anchor

Below is my current code

```
      blobService.startCopyBlob(url, container, filename,{
            metadata: {
                'url': url,
            }}, function(error) {
    if (!error) {
        context.log('Message inserted:', text);
    }
    else {
        context.log('All done'); 
        context.done()
    }
});
```

All the metadata returns is 'url': https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine.

You could either use [getBlobMetadata()](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#getBlobMetadata__anchor) function or [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to check the metadata after saving blob.

[image]

Comment: Hmm - that is interesting. If I search properties on Storage Explorer then I do get the url as I want. However if I look at the metadata on Azure Portal  then that is when it only shows 'url': https. Any ideas why?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Azure Portal if the value of Metadata includes a colon (:). You can send Azure team feedback for this in Azure Portal.